# change color of nodes in pgfplots bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I have a bar plot which print the number next to the bar.
The text is however not very well readable due to the color applied to it.

Therefore I would like to know how to modify its style.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false, col sep=comma]{ % Read data table. 
% First row doesn't have column names, hence the "header=false"
1, first item
5, second item
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ,xbar
    ,bar width=2ex, y=3ex
    ,nodes near coords 
    ,nodes near coords align={horizontal} 
    % my approach:
    ,every node near coords/.append style={color=red}
    %%        
    ,enlarge y limits={abs=0.75}
    ,ytick={data} % (\empty,data,{coordinate list})
    ,yticklabels from table={\datatable}{1}
  ]
  \addplot table [
    y expr=-\coordindex, % Use negative coordinate index as y coordinate
    x index=0 % Use first column as x coordinate
  ] {\datatable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Small typo: The style is called `every node near coord`.